# Make a node not affect graph layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, pygraphviz

I am trying to make a node without affecting the positioning of connected nodes. When I plot the graph, it centers the parent node between the children nodes; this is causing the staggered effect.  How can I make the failure node not affect the layout of the other nodes?  I have already made the lines straight like they are in the desired photo, but it still has the staggered layout.

Current style:

[image: Current style]

Desired style:

[image: Desired Style]

EDIT:
Dot Code

```
strict graph "" {
graph [bb="0,0,562,490",
    bgcolor="#666666",
    fontcolor=white,
    fontname=monospace,
    label="ACI MSC - Create Bridge Domain - L3",
    labelfontsize=40,
    labelloc=t,
    lheight=0.19,
    lp="281,479",
    lwidth=3.30,
    newrank=yes,
    nodesep=0.2,
    outputorder=edgesfirst,
    overlap=compress,
    ranksep=0.5,
    splines=spline
];
node [fillcolor=white,
    fixedsize=True,
    fontcolor=black,
    fontname=monospace,
    label="\N",
    shape=rectangle,
    style=filled,
    width=5.125
];
edge [fontname=monospace,
    fontsize=15,
    penwidth=2
];
Start    [color=white,
    fillcolor=blue,
    fixedsize=false,
    fontcolor=white,
    height=0.5,
    pos="377.5,450",
    shape=oval,
    width=1];
"ACIMSC-CreateSchemaandAddTemplate-Sub"  [height=0.5,
    pos="377.5,378"];
Start -- "ACIMSC-CreateSchemaandAddTemplate-Sub"     [color=green,
    pos="377.5,431.83 377.5,421 377.5,407.29 377.5,396.41"];
"ACIMSC-AddBridgeDomaintoTemplate"   [height=0.5,
    pos="274.5,306"];
"ACIMSC-CreateSchemaandAddTemplate-Sub" -- "ACIMSC- 
AddBridgeDomaintoTemplate"   [color=green,
    pos="351.51,359.83 335.89,348.92 316.1,335.08 300.48,324.16"];
Fail     [color=white,
    fillcolor=red,
    fixedsize=false,
    fontcolor=white,
    height=0.5,
    pos="421.5,18",
    shape=oval,
    weight=0,
    width=1];
"ACIMSC-CreateSchemaandAddTemplate-Sub" -- Fail  [color=red,
    pos="423.22,359.95 439.3,351.39 455.96,339.56 466.5,324 
    489.24,290.42 481.5,274.55 481.5,234 481.5,234 481.5,234 
    481.5,162 
    481.5,120.71 \
    475.54,109.6 458.5,72 452.5,58.75 443.25,45.25 435.5,35.063"];
"ACIMSC-AddBridgeDomaintoTemplate" -- Fail   [color=red,
    pos="356.37,288 391.19,278.55 426.17,266.02 436.5,252 
    485.39,185.63 447.55,77.845 429.6,35.692"];
VscaleACIMultisiteAddSubnettoBridgeDomain    [height=0.5,
    pos="244.5,234"];
"ACIMSC-AddBridgeDomaintoTemplate" -- 
VscaleACIMultisiteAddSubnettoBridgeDomain    [color=green,
    pos="266.93,287.83 262.42,277 256.7,263.29 252.17,252.41"];
VscaleACIMultisiteAddSubnettoBridgeDomain -- Fail    [color=red,
    pos="325.05,215.91 360.06,206.35 395.58,193.76 406.5,180 
    439.94,137.85 431.92,68.723 425.62,36.11"];
"ACIMSC-AddL3OuttoSiteBridgeDomain-Sub"  [height=0.5,
    pos="214.5,162"];
VscaleACIMultisiteAddSubnettoBridgeDomain -- "ACIMSC- 
AddL3OuttoSiteBridgeDomain-Sub"  [color=green,
    pos="236.93,215.83 232.42,205 226.7,191.29 222.17,180.41"];
"ACIMSC-AddL3OuttoSiteBridgeDomain-Sub" -- Fail  [color=red,
    pos="309.72,143.87 333.49,135.88 357.57,124.41 376.5,108 
    398.54,88.885 410.97,56.41 416.96,36.139"];
"ACIMSC-DeployTemplatetoSites"   [height=0.5,
    pos="184.5,90"];
"ACIMSC-AddL3OuttoSiteBridgeDomain-Sub" -- "ACIMSC- 
DeployTemplatetoSites"   [color=green,
    pos="206.93,143.83 202.42,133 196.7,119.29 192.17,108.41"];
"ACIMSC-DeployTemplatetoSites" -- Fail   [color=red,
    pos="244,71.924 290.62,57.761 353.6,38.629 390.65,27.373"];
Complete     [color=white,
    fillcolor="#129112",
    fixedsize=false,
    fontcolor=white,
    height=0.5,
    pos="184.5,18",
    shape=oval,
    width=1.3321];
"ACIMSC-DeployTemplatetoSites" -- Complete   [color=green,
    pos="184.5,71.831 184.5,61 184.5,47.288 184.5,36.413"];
}
```

Comment: Please post your dot code you tried sofar so it is possible to start from theer.

Comment: Hey Albert.  I posted the dot code.  This code was generated using pygraphviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't render your code to achieve your picture, but the techniques I'm about to suggest should work anyway.

I've composed a similar basic example code:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=rect]

    a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
    success [shape=oval]
    f -> success
    {
        rank=max
        failure [shape=oval]
    }
    {a b c d e f} -> failure
}
```

This gives following picture with your issue reproduced:

[image]

**First possible solution** may be to add [constraint](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:constraint)`=false` attribute to the edges leading to `falure` node. This attribute does just that - prevents the edge from affecting the layout.

```
digraph {
    node [shape=rect]

    a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f
    success [shape=oval]
    f -> success
    {
        rank=max
        failure [shape=oval]
    }
    {a b c d e f} -> failure [constraint=false]
}
```

Result:

[image]

**Second possible solution** would be to increase the [weight](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:weight) attribute of the edges which you need to remain straight. Edges with higher weight tend to be shorter and straighter than the others:

```
digraph {
    node [shape=rect]

    a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f [weight=10]
    success [shape=oval]
    f -> success
    {
        rank=max
        failure [shape=oval]
    }
    {a b c d e f} -> failure
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey Dany.  Thanks for the response!  I ended up using the weight.  When using constraint=False, I was getting the following result:
https://imgur.com/a/CAzGvXs

The weight kept the failure node at the bottom.

Comment: But if you know how to keep failure fropm going to the top, let me know :) the lines are cleaner in that version.

Comment: Hi, @DavidPryor! You can enclose the `Failure` node in a subgraph with `rank=max` attribute, just like I did in all my examples. This forces the node to stay at the bottom no matter what. Also you could enclose both `success` and `failure` definitions into a subgraph with `rank=same` attribute. This will force them to stay at the same level.
  https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:rank

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  I ended up using a combination of weights and constraint=false to get a nice layout!  I also ended up using an invisible connection between complete and fail to ensure they would maintain their relative orientation to each other;  constraint= false would sometimes flip complete and fail.